# Runtime out of memory on RPi with ethereum node

Tags: synchronization, raspberry-pi

I have a private network of ethereum with 2 miners on my PC and a node on RPi, after syncing it says:
Fatal: runtime: out of memory

The sd card is 16Gb and it should have plenty of free space, is RAM the problem?

What can I do?
Thanks

Comment: Yes, memory in this case means RAM.

Comment: What can I do to avoid this?

Comment: Which model RPi are you using? How much memory (RAM) does it have?